# CMultiSelect from CoreUI-pro doesn't have style

Tags: reactjs

I'm using CMultiSelect from coreUI-pro, but it has no style, it seemed ugly.

Here is the component :

```
import { CMultiSelect } from "@coreui/react-pro";
    <CMultiSelect 
        options={[{value:1,text:"React"},{value: 6, text: 'Node.js'}]}
        label="Users"text="Please select your user."
        virtualScroller
        className='search-drop-down-list'
        optionsStyle={'checkbox'} 
    />
```

and here is the imported styles in style.scss

```
@import "~@coreui/coreui-pro/scss/coreui.scss";   
@import '~@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css';
```

The docs :
https://coreui.io/react/docs/forms/multi-select/#api

I need to beautify it, as shown in docs
https://coreui.io/react/docs/forms/multi-select/#api

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by importing the coreui pro css file in my own project's css file. My project is in Replit, so I'm not sure if the phrasing would be different for you, and the import line looks like:
`import '@coreui/coreui-pro/dist/css/coreui.min.css'`

Hope this helps!